# remove existing file returns FileNotFoundError

Tags: python

I have an existing file in a mounted folder, which I verify by

```
os.path.isfile(config.inpath + file)
True
```

But the following returns a FileNotFoundError

```
os.remove(config.inpath + file)
*** FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

Also,

```
os.system('rm ' + config.inpath + file)
```

doesn't work. However, I can remove the file from the terminal.

Any idea why this is not working within python?

**EDIT:**

I don't know if this helps, but here would be the exact error message

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/operations/mnt/CustomerFolder/TESTSSTEM/filename.xml'
```

Unfortunately,

```
os.remove(os.path.join(config.inpfad, file))

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

also doesn't work.

The file ist not a symbolic link either.

Comment: interesting. Could you please add the entire error message, including the name of the file?

Comment: Please read [ask] and extract a [mcve].

Comment: Are you sure that you have not already deleted the file and now get an error by calling `os.remove` a second time?

Comment: can you try `os.remove(os.path.join(filepath, file))`?

Comment: Possibly related ? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44906/rm-cant-delete-file

Comment: I don't think you've included the actual file name. The reason I'm asking - could it be that it contains some special characters?

Comment: @mkrieger1: The two commands os.path.isdir() and os.remove() are called one after another. So the file is not accidentily deleted. I can still see it in the folder.

Comment: @Roy2012: Sorry, I can't post the actual filename and CustomerFolder. But there are no special characters involved.

Comment: @Ulrich Eckhardt: I know this is a tough question and probably not reproducible. In my 7 years of python programming I haven't seen this before.

Comment: Could it be that the file is a symbolic link, and not a regular file? According to the documentation, isfile returns true for links. (https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile)

Comment: What OS are you running on, and what's the mounted file system?

Comment: @Roy2012: 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.130-2 (2018-10-27) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: maybe first display `print( 'rm ' + config.inpath + file )` and use displayed text directly in console/terminal (without Python) to see if you have problem to delete it. Maybe problem is not Python but some privilages in system.

Answer (score 0):

Thank's to everyone who helped me finding the error.

Actually,

```
os.system('rm -f ' + config.inpath + file)
```

works fine.

Comment: (1) Great. (2) you should consider using os.path.join(config.inpath, file) instead of the "+" operator.